# using repeated macros in c++

Tags: c++, c, macros

assume i have a macro like this
`#define MY_MACRO(n) xxxxxxxxx // some code`

then I want to use it many times like

```
MY_MACRO(0)
MY_MACRO(1)
MY_MACRO(2)
MY_MACRO(3)
...
MY_MACRO(100)
```

is there a better way of doing this? (I have to use macros)

Comment: Yeah, don't use macros!

Comment: Why do you think that you need to use macros, especially in C++ where there are much better alternatives ?

Comment: Write a program to create the macro calls. I'd use Python where it would be about 3 lines of code, but even in C or C++ it wouldn't be so bad.

Comment: Without knowing *anything* about your code, I'd be willing to bet 42 cents you can use template metaprogramming instead of macros here.

Comment: Without more info about what your macro does, we cannot provide a comprehensive solution. More info/code is needed.

Comment: You _have_ to use macros? Is this homework?

Comment: Guys, sometimes macros are necessary.  Even in the task of doing TMP, especially in C++03, macros are essential.  Further, such iteration is essential.  Bigotry against macros, scary as they are, is not helpful.  Just have a look at the TMP library itself or read Abraham's book.

Comment: @CrazyEddie: While I agree with you, I have to say that I don't see anything here to suggest that a macro is particularly beneficial in this case. It *could* be anyway, but nothing he's say really says so.

Comment: you should look at http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/inline-vs-macros.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget all the <s>highly-educated teoreticians</s> critics that just say **NEVER-EVER-EVER** dare to use macros!

Macros indeed are the necessary evil. Yes, *sometimes* there are other options, such as templates, polymorphism and other things. But **not always** it's possible to get rid from repetitions without the user of macros.

And, in my humble opinion, macros are a better alternative than rewriting the same thing endless times.

Now regarding your question. If your macro evaluates to an expression where its parameter may be a run-time parameter - you may use a loop.

If your macro demands a compile-time known constant - you may consider using templates (if applicable).

If your macro demands an **expression** which is a numerical constant - there are no alternatives left.

All I can suggest is instead of actually repeating your macro 100 times you may do some tricks, such as the following:

```
#define MACRO_IX10(m, i) \
    m(i##0) \
    m(i##1) \
    m(i##2) \
    m(i##3) \
    m(i##4) \
    m(i##5) \
    m(i##6) \
    m(i##7) \
    m(i##8) \
    m(i##9)

#define MACRO_IX100(m) \
    MACRO_IX10(m, ) \
    MACRO_IX10(m, 1) \
    MACRO_IX10(m, 2) \
    MACRO_IX10(m, 3) \
    MACRO_IX10(m, 4) \
    MACRO_IX10(m, 5) \
    MACRO_IX10(m, 6) \
    MACRO_IX10(m, 7) \
    MACRO_IX10(m, 8) \
    MACRO_IX10(m, 9)
```

Then you may do this:

```
MACRO_IX100(MYMACRO)
```

It's equivalent to invoking your macro 100 times with the appropriate expressions.

Answer (score 6):

You can use iteration.  You can use boost's preprocessor library or write your own.  Good luck on the latter...it's frickin complicated.  Preprocessor metaprogramming is tricky business.

Using boost preprocessor you would do something like so:

```
#define MY_MACRO_N(Z,N,D) MY_MACRO(N)

BOOST_PP_REPEAT(101, MY_MACRO_N, ~)
```

Comment: This is cool. I wasn't aware of `BOOST_PP_REPEAT`. Sounds very useful

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    MY_MACRO(i);
```

By using this loop `MY_MACRO(n)` whould be called 101 times with the current value of `i` (`0` to `100`).

Comment: +1, but with the `//` in the macro I'd play it safe and put the semicolon on a new line.

Comment: This fails if the parameter begin passed to MY_MACRO needs to be a compile-time constant.

Comment: @PaulR The question is what the OP requires in the first place.

Comment: doesnt this call it 101 times?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the post with `<=` and forgot that this will be 101 times ;)

Comment: 101 times is the same as what the OP wanted.